# Kineticjs doesn't work with a nexus 4 straight out of the box

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, kineticjs, nexus

I recently bought a Nexus 4 (yesterday), but realised to my horror that no Kineticjs code seems to work on this. Has anyone else experienced this and know if there is a way to get it to work? I have literally not done any updates on the nexus (Package invalid errors :-S)

Thanks

Alex.

Comment: can you check the adb log and see what errors are thrown when your site is loaded? Was this code working on any other android device before?

Comment: you'll have to add the site details / code here where the error is thrown to get any meaningful answers

Comment: This is the tutorial site I was referring to   http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/

Comment: Literally none of these examples are working with the nexus 4.

Comment: did you see any errors in adb?

Comment: This is probably something that should be posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues) instead of StackOverflow. I would open an issue there if you haven't already. Also as suggested here you should try to figure out what errors are being thrown using ADB.

Comment: Is everything necessary (like JavaScript) activated in your browser? On my Nexus 4 all of the above labs work as expected (some of them are not designed for mobile devices, so mouse events obviously don't work at all in these specific examples)... What do you mean with `doesn't work`? Don't you see anything at all when you open an example or can you see the drawings and just the events aren't working?

Comment: Nothing is displayed at all for the demos from html5canvastutorials.com. And yes, javascript is enabled as it works for other canvas examples that don't use kineticjs.